# Error calling ImageDataGenerator.flow in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, image-processing

I am working on image augmentation with images having numeric target value for regression problem, and got the error "ValueError: Unsupported channel number: 150". The code and full stack trace is below.

```
x_dataset=[]
for file in glob.glob(img):
  a=cv2.imread(file, 0)
  a=cv2.resize(a, (150, 150))
  a=a/255.
  x_dataset.append(a)
```

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=90,  # rotate images up to 20 degrees
    horizontal_flip=True,  # flip images horizontally
    vertical_flip=True  # flip images vertically
)
```

```
X.shape

(1, 30, 150, 150)
```

```
y.shape

(1, 30)
```

```
i=0
for batch in datagen.flow (X, y, batch_size=32, 
                           save_to_dir='aug', 
                           save_format='png'):
  i +=1
  if i> 20:
   break
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-7ca22a93f1b2> in <module>
      1 i=0
----> 2 for batch in datagen.flow (X, y, batch_size=32, 
      3                            save_to_dir='aug',
      4                            save_format='png'):
      5   i +=1

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    154 
    155     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 156         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    157 
    158     def next(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in next(self)
    166         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    167         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 168         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    169 
    170     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    807         if self.save_to_dir:
    808             for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
--> 809                 img = image_utils.array_to_img(
    810                     batch_x[i], self.data_format, scale=True
    811                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/image_utils.py in array_to_img(x, data_format, scale, dtype)
    277         return pil_image.fromarray(x[:, :, 0].astype("uint8"), "L")
    278     else:
--> 279         raise ValueError(f"Unsupported channel number: {x.shape[2]}")
    280 
    281 

ValueError: Unsupported channel number: 150
```

Please help me to come out of this error

Answer (score 2):

I see, the problem is in your shape:
In X.shape you have (1, 30, 150, 150), but in keras it expects this: (30, 150, 150, 1) which is (batch_size, height, width, channel).
I guess your images are in gray scale so it has only 1 channel.

And for the Y shape you just need (30,).